# What is and How to use the Store API from React Native Navigation?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-navigation

React-Native-Navigation has poor documentation. I wonder what its `Store` [API](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/api/Store) is for.

One of its methods is called `setPropsForId`. Right now I don't get even more than 10 Google results for `setPropsForId`!! Apparently it's useful for passing props back on navigator pop. How to get the id to be used in such call, for example?